# iOS, how should I setup recurring local push notifications, like every 1st of the month?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'd like to setup recurring local push notifications.

I need to set them to recur say each month on the 1st of the month.

From what I've seen, I think I'd need to setup each recurrence separately. I mean 1st of January, 1st of February etc.

Is this correct ?

In my app the user may wish to setup several different notifications.

I guess I'm going to have to require users to use my app every so often to ensure that notifications are added. I mean I don't want to add too many notifications to the que?

Any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it to fire on the first of the month and then do:

> yourLocalNotification.repeatInterval = NSMonthCalendarUnit;

Answer (score 1):

You can set a repeat interval when scheduling the local notification ;-)
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html